# writing image and filter classes

Tags: python, numpy

```
class Filter:
    def apply(self, img_np_array):
        return (self.img_np_array)
```

I'm new to this class thing and I am kind of lost. So, I want to write a class called filter and a function call apply that takes numpy image as an argument and returns it unchanged. This is what I have. I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: No, that won't work because you haven't assigned anything to `self.img_np_array`. But why do you want a method that just returns its argument?

Comment: This is what my instructor wants .-.

Comment: You can get that method to return the Numpy array by changing its return statement to `return img_np_array`, but I think you need to explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do I need to take out the self in the apply(self,img_np_array) too?

Comment: No, you can't take out the `self` because all normal instance methods have `self` as the first arg in their signature. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html